# Method executeScript( java.lang.String, org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement )

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

I am writing code for Jmeter webdriver Sampler when I use Javascript executor  I am getting error as
Sourced file: inline evaluation of:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*; 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;  
import o . . . '' :
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error in method invocation: Method executeScript( java.lang.String, org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement ) not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver' :
```

I am getting error at line:

```
WebElement checkItemOnly=WDS.browser.findElement(By.xpath("//td[span[text()='Create Item Only']]/following-sibling::td//input[@type='checkbox']"));

JavascriptExecutor jse2 = (JavascriptExecutor)WDS.browser;
jse2.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", checkItemOnly);
               
checkItemOnly.click();
```

I am using Java as a language and chrome browser. I am stucked due to this error.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no such a language as `java` in the WebDriver Sampler, what you think being Java is actually [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/)
2. There is no need to cast `WDS.browser` to JavascriptExecutor

So given you:

- Change the language to `groovy`
- Change these lines:

  ```
  JavascriptExecutor jse2 = (JavascriptExecutor)WDS.browser;
  jse2.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", checkItemOnly);
  ```

  to this one:

  ```
  WDS.browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", checkItemOnly)
  ```

your code should start working more or less as you expect it to work

More information:

- [JMeter Best Practices - Beanshell scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)